# Create new data containing text according to the row number R studio

Tags: r, text-mining

I have a dataset containing text and it has 1 variable and 801 observations. I want to create a new column for each variable related to row number however I am new to R and don't know how to do it. I want to achieve this:

```
   Text     Newcol
1   blue    text1
2   green   text2       
3   black   text3      
4   red     text4     
5   yellow  text5         
6   orange  text6
```

How can I do this? Please help me

Comment: You can do `df1$Newcol <- paste0('text', seq_len(nrow(df1)))`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
your_data$Newcol <- paste0("text", 1:nrow(your_data))
```